# Latex Pstricks inserting a node inside a blurbox

Tags: pstricks

The following  code works as I was expecting but it generates an error. How 
 to remove the it

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-blur}

\begin{document}

\psblurbox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray!10,linestyle=none]{\begin{tabular}{l}

Soit une $(n-)$\textit{boucle} {\rnode{A}{$J_0$} {\protect$\rightarrow~\cdots~\rightarrow$~\rnode{B}{$J_{n-1}$}%
\ncarc[linewidth=.5pt,node sep=5pt, offset=3pt]{->}{B}{A}}}, alors il existe \\un point fixe $p$ de $f^n$ tel que $f^i(p) \in J_i$ pour $0\leq i < n$.
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strokeopacity` to make the expoenent i more readable:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[svgnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-blur}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\psblurbox[fillcolor=gray!10,linestyle=none]{\parbox{0.7\linewidth}{%
    Soit une $(n-)$\textit{boucle} \rnode{A}{$J_0$} 
    $\rightarrow~\cdots~\rightarrow$~\rnode{B}{$J_{n-1}$}%
    \ncarc[linewidth=.5pt,offset=3pt,strokeopacity=0.5]{->}{B}{A}, alors il existe 
    un point fixe $p$ de $f^n$ tel que $f^i(p) \in J_i$ pour $0\leq 
    i < n$.%
}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`node sep` is the culprit. And you forgot a `\begin{center}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-blur}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\psblurbox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray!10,linestyle=none]{\begin{tabular}{l}

Soit une $(n-)$\textit{boucle} {\rnode{A}{$J_0$} {\protect$\rightarrow~\cdots~\rightarrow$~\rnode{B}{$J_{n-1}$}%
\ncarc[linewidth=.5pt,offset=3pt]{->}{B}{A}}}, alors il existe \\un point fixe $p$ de $f^n$ tel que $f^i(p) \in J_i$ pour $0\leq i < n$.
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks marmot. I wonder why nodesep doesn't work.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki Very simple: `node sep` is Ti*k*Z syntax, for PSTricks use `nodesep`, so no separation between `node` and `sep` ;-) But you were saying you were fine with the output so I just dropped it.

Comment: marmot. Obviously, I have not seen the space I introduced in nodesep. It was a pure error of mine. I apologized. I use pstricks now since 20 years and I made again and again stupid error. I recognize that this post may be not very usefull to others. Nevertheless thanks again.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki Strange logic but of course you are the boss. ;-) (What if someone would post a Ti*k*Z pic which as an even nicer output?)

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen your comment sooner. It would be interesting to have a TikZ code. I not using Tikz because when it appears I wazs involved with pstricks. I wonder if one can mix both.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki I think you should ask a new question then. The answers are not just for you, but for everyone. Imagine you have a problem, find a question on it, but the answer is on something else. That's why I am not 100% happy with how things went here. I do not care about the reputation, but about providing appropriate answers on questions such that other might find question and answer useful.

Comment: You are once more time true. I will ask the question. But here I was not expecting an answer.